# Acessing Play Asset Delivery files in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-play, flutter-dependencies, android-assets, dynamic-delivery

I have an Android App built in Flutter. It uses a lot of audio and video files, so it is over 150mb in size. Even after compressing everthing. So I tried implementing the Play Asset Delivery feature, that Google provides. Followed this guide: https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/asset-delivery/integrate-java . I had sucess creating an Appbundle with audio files on my asset_delivery library. The problem is now that i cant get my App to access the files and play the Audio. I tried plugins like the flutter_play_asset_delivery, but the documentation on there is just too poor and doesn't help me any further. Is there any method to actually implement Play Asset Delivery in Flutter (in a useful/functioning way) or am I stuck here?

I tried alternatives like the deferred components but that also didn't have any documentation regarding to assets like audio and video files. I also didn't find any other useful plugin.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.